# How to debug a complex nested SQL statement for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables as below,

```
table a ( eid, COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, COLUMND)

1001,1,1,0,1
1002,1,0,0,0




table b (id, description)
1, ABC
2, BCD
3,CDE
4,DEF
```

Note: description will be related to table1 columns, usually; these are checkboxes on the ui, so desciption = checkbox names from ui.

```
table c(eid, groupid)
```

My question is, I need to migrate the data from table1 into table 3 as below

```
1001,1
1001,2
1001,4
1002,1
```

Below is my query, but not getting the results as I expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT eid, id
    FROM (SELECT eid,
                 CASE
                    WHEN cola = 1
                    THEN
                       (SELECT id
                          FROM tableb
                         WHERE description = 'ABC')
                    WHEN cola = 0
                    THEN
                       -1
                 END
                    AS coln_a,
                 CASE
                    WHEN colb = 1
                    THEN
                       (SELECT id
                          FROM tableb
                         WHERE description = 'BCD')
                    WHEN colb = 0
                    THEN
                       -1
                 END
                    AS coln_b,
                 CASE
                    WHEN colc = 1
                    THEN
                       (SELECT id
                          FROM tableb
                         WHERE description = 'CDE')
                    WHEN colc = 0
                    THEN
                       -1
                 END
                    AS coln_c,
                 CASE
                    WHEN cold = 1
                    THEN
                       (SELECT id
                          FROM tableb
                         WHERE description = 'DEF')
                    WHEN cold = 0
                    THEN
                       -1
                 END
                    AS coln_d
            FROM tablea
           WHERE cola = 1 OR colb = 1 OR colc = 1 OR cold= 1) temp_t,
         tableb
   WHERE coln_a = id OR coln_b = id OR coln_c = id OR coln_d = id
ORDER BY eid, id;
```

what is the mistake?

Comment: Can you explain your logic better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accomplish this by doing a series of unions:

```
(SELECT eid, 1 AS groupid FROM tablea WHERE COLUMNA = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT eid, 2 FROM tablea WHERE COLUMNB = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT eid, 3 FROM tablea WHERE COLUMNC = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT eid, 4 FROM tablea WHERE COLUMND = 1)
```

I don't see how the B table is related to the immediate output you want.

Comment: Tim..Thanks a lot for the answer..it really worked..!!